# Stm Cube IDE ERROR : Comparison error for function

Tags: function, arm, return, comparison

I am experimenting with the STM32f407vg board through the STMBUBEIDE program.

First of all, I prepare my own library file and make the settings in the interrupt section.

What if the reason I can't get rid of this error?

First of all, I have a griodriver.c file for my src file. And my definition in it:

```
  uint8_t portcode = GPIO_BASE_ADDR_TO_CODE (pGPIOHandle-> pGPIOx);
```

Then I write my function so that this comes back.

```
 uint16_t GPIO_BASE_ADDR_TO_CODE(*x)
    {
        if(x==GPIOA)        { return 0; }
        else if(x==GPIOB)   { return 1; }
        else if(x==GPIOC)   { return 2; }
        else if(x==GPIOD)   { return 3; }
        else if(x==GPIOE)   { return 4; }
        else if(x==GPIOF)   { return 5; }
        else if(x==GPIOG)   { return 6; }

    }
```

If I remove the pointer inside the loop, I get a comparison between pointer and interger error.

Whenever I compile I get an error.

My error says this for the function:
This is warnings error.

```
     Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
     implicit declaration of function 'GPIO_BASE_ADDR_TO_CODE'; did you mean 'GPIOJ_BASEADDR'? 
      [- Wimplicit-function-declaration]    stm32f407xx_gpio_driver.c   /stm32f407xx/drivers/Src     
      line 253  C/C++ Problem
```

But there are 2 other errors I get as ERROR.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF5Ia.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkUyY.png)

First:

```
          1. ERROR:  Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
          make: *** [drivers/Src/subdir.mk:18: drivers/Src/stm32f407xx_gpio_driver.o]            
         Error 1    stm32f407xx         C/C++ Problem
```

SEcond:

```
               Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
              expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token stm32f407xx_gpio_driver.c    
              /stm32f407xx/drivers/Src  line 168    C/C++ Problem
```

Error Screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wevC3.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I change this part like a below,

```
 uint16_t GPIO_BASE_ADDR_TO_CODE(uint8_t x)
    {
        if( x==GPIOA)   { return 0; }
        else if(x==GPIOB)   { return 1; }
        else if(x==GPIOC)   { return 2; }
        else if(x==GPIOD)   { return 3; }
        else if(x==GPIOE)   { return 4; }
        else if(x==GPIOF)   { return 5; }
        else if(x==GPIOG)   { return 6; }

        return 0;

    }
```

My errors change like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X48uE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling it in a function, I defined it as #define for

```
          GPIO_BASEADDR_TO_CODE
```

Also removed if else condition. I used a C third conditional.

Now is no errors after 3 days later:))

You can see it below pictures what I did.

```
  #define GPIO_BASEADDR_TO_CODE(x)  ((x == GPIOA)?0 :\
                                    (x == GPIOB)?1 :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)? :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)?3 :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)?4 :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)?5 :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)?6 :\
                                    (x == GPIOA)?7 :0 )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RluQ.png)